# PHP - Run the same php function multiple times on the same file

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a database / table list sort of system, where it will display the current likes/dislikes of a user. The likes/dislikes of a user is fetched, and managed by a function from a seperate file, called `displayRating()`. I use require_once to call the seperate file that it is located in, at the beginning of my list, then get down to business.

I then go ahead and have my

```
foreach(...){
...
displayRating($id);
...
}
```

However I'm getting an error, which seems to be telling me that I can't call a function multiple times within the same page. Here is my exact (unoptimized) code:

**vote.php**

```
<?php
function displayRating($id){
    if(isset($id)){
        require_once('medoo.min.php');
        // Start up the D.B. Connection
        $database = new medoo([
        // required
        'database_type' => 'mysql',
        'database_name' => '****',
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '****',
        'password' => '****',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        // driver_option for connection, read more from http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
        'option' => [
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
        ]]);
        // xf_user_field_value DB. Amount of ratings: 506c617965725f7261746573    Current Score: 706c617965725f726174696e67
        $accountinfo = $database->select('xf_user_field_value', ['field_value'], ["user_id"=>$id]);
        $vScore = $accountinfo[5]['field_value'];
        // Processing Time
        $phrase = '<div class="bc"><div data-hint="%1$s" class="hint--right vote %2$s"></div></div>';
        if($vScore == 0){
            printf($phrase, 'Neutral Score', 'v_equal');
            return;
        } elseif ($vScore > 0){
            // Positive Here
            switch($vScore){
                case 1:
                    printf($phrase, '1 Like', 'v_p1 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf($phrase, '2 Likes', 'v_p2 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf($phrase, '3 Likes', 'v_p3 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf($phrase, '4 Likes', 'v_p4 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf($phrase, '5 Likes', 'v_p5 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf($phrase, '6 Likes', 'v_p6 hint--success');
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf($phrase, '7 Likes', 'v_p7 hint--success');
                    break;
                default:
                    printf($phrase, $vScore . ' Likes', 'v_p7 hint-success');
                    break;
            }
        } elseif ($vScore < 0){
            // Negative Here
            switch($vScore){
                case -1:
                    printf($phrase, '1 Dislike', 'v_m1 hint--error');
                    break;
                default:
                    if($vScore < -7){ $vClass = 7; } else { $vClass = abs($vScore); }
                    printf($phrase, abs($vScore) . ' Dislikes', 'v_m' . $vClass . ' hint--error');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

**displayCodes.php**

```
<?php
function displayCodesMain($page){ 
    if($page == 1){?>
<table class="friendcodes">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Friend Code</th>
        <th>Affinity</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$plisting = file_get_contents('plist.txt');
$plist = explode(' ', $plisting, 4);
require_once('vote.php');
array_pop($plist);
    foreach($plist as $item) {
        $item = explode(':', $item);
        echo '<tr class="fc_premium">';
        $item[3] = substr($item[3], 0, 3) . '-' . substr($item[3], 3, 7);
        $item[1] = str_replace('&', ' ', $item[1]);
        echo '<td>' . $item[1] . '</td><td>' . $item[3] . '</td><td style="text-transform:capitalize;">' . $item[4] . '</td><td>' . $item[5] . '</td><td>  <div class="bc"><div class="vote v_p7"> </div></div> </td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
$listing = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$list = explode(' ', $listing, 26);
array_pop($list);
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $item = explode(':', $item);
        echo '<tr class="fc_regular">';
        $item[3] = substr($item[3], 0, 3) . '-' . substr($item[3], 3, 7);
        $item[1] = str_replace('&', ' ', $item[1]);
        echo '<td>' . $item[1] . '</td><td>' . $item[3] . '</td><td style="text-transform:capitalize;">' . $item[4] . '</td><td>' . $item[5] . '</td><td>'. displayRating($item[0]) .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }

    echo '</table>';
} else if($page == 2) { 
// Start page #2 management
?>
<table class="friendcodes">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Friend Code</th>
        <th>Affinity</th>
        <th>Level</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$listing = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$list = explode(' ', $listing, 51);
$list = array_slice($list, 25, 25);
array_pop($list);
    foreach($list as $item) {
        $item = explode(':', $item);
        echo '<tr class="fc_regular">';
        $item[3] = substr($item[3], 0, 3) . '-' . substr($item[3], 3, 7);
        $item[1] = str_replace('&', ' ', $item[1]);
        echo '<td>' . $item[1] . '</td><td>' . $item[3] . '</td><td style="text-transform:capitalize;">' . $item[4] . '</td><td>' . $item[5] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
?>
    </table>
    <?php
}
} // Close the function
?>
```

**Test.php** (What I'm using to dynamically get values and whatnot - warning, contains some CSS, which you can safely skip over.

```
<?php
/*include('newUser.php');
addNewUser('1', 'true', 'Spitfire', '8JX-UKR8', 'Spirit', '90');*/
require('displayCodes.php');
displayCodesMain(1);
?>
<head>


<style>
/*! Hint.css - v1.3.2 - 2014-05-18
* http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/
* Copyright (c) 2014 Kushagra Gour; Licensed MIT */

.hint,[data-hint]{position:relative;display:inline-block}.hint:before,.hint:after,[data-hint]:before,[data-hint]:after{position:absolute;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);visibility:hidden;opacity:0;z-index:1000000;pointer-events:none;-webkit-transition:.3s ease;-moz-transition:.3s ease;transition:.3s ease;-webkit-transition-delay:0ms;-moz-transition-delay:0ms;transition-delay:0ms}.hint:hover:before,.hint:hover:after,.hint:focus:before,.hint:focus:after,[data-hint]:hover:before,[data-hint]:hover:after,[data-hint]:focus:before,[data-hint]:focus:after{visibility:visible;opacity:1}.hint:hover:before,.hint:hover:after,[data-hint]:hover:before,[data-hint]:hover:after{-webkit-transition-delay:100ms;-moz-transition-delay:100ms;transition-delay:100ms}.hint:before,[data-hint]:before{content:'';position:absolute;background:transparent;border:6px solid transparent;z-index:1000001}.hint:after,[data-hint]:after{content:attr(data-hint);background:#383838;color:#fff;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #000;padding:8px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:12px;white-space:nowrap;box-shadow:4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3)}.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#383838}.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#383838}.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#383838}.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#383838}.hint--top:before{margin-bottom:-12px}.hint--top:after{margin-left:-18px}.hint--top:before,.hint--top:after{bottom:100%;left:50%}.hint--top:hover:after,.hint--top:hover:before,.hint--top:focus:after,.hint--top:focus:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--bottom:before{margin-top:-12px}.hint--bottom:after{margin-left:-18px}.hint--bottom:before,.hint--bottom:after{top:100%;left:50%}.hint--bottom:hover:after,.hint--bottom:hover:before,.hint--bottom:focus:after,.hint--bottom:focus:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--right:before{margin-left:-12px;margin-bottom:-6px}.hint--right:after{margin-bottom:-14px}.hint--right:before,.hint--right:after{left:100%;bottom:50%}.hint--right:hover:after,.hint--right:hover:before,.hint--right:focus:after,.hint--right:focus:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(8px);transform:translateX(8px)}.hint--left:before{margin-right:-12px;margin-bottom:-6px}.hint--left:after{margin-bottom:-14px}.hint--left:before,.hint--left:after{right:100%;bottom:50%}.hint--left:hover:after,.hint--left:hover:before,.hint--left:focus:after,.hint--left:focus:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-8px);transform:translateX(-8px)}.hint--error:after{background-color:#b34e4d;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #592726}.hint--error.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#b34e4d}.hint--error.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#b34e4d}.hint--warning:after{background-color:#c09854;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #6c5328}.hint--warning.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#c09854}.hint--warning.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#c09854}.hint--info:after{background-color:#3986ac;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #193b4d}.hint--info.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#3986ac}.hint--info.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#3986ac}.hint--success:after{background-color:#458746;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #1a321a}.hint--success.hint--top:before{border-top-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--bottom:before{border-bottom-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--left:before{border-left-color:#458746}.hint--success.hint--right:before{border-right-color:#458746}.hint--always:after,.hint--always:before{opacity:1;visibility:visible}.hint--always.hint--top:after,.hint--always.hint--top:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);-moz-transform:translateY(-8px);transform:translateY(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--bottom:after,.hint--always.hint--bottom:before{-webkit-transform:translateY(8px);-moz-transform:translateY(8px);transform:translateY(8px)}.hint--always.hint--left:after,.hint--always.hint--left:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(-8px);-moz-transform:translateX(-8px);transform:translateX(-8px)}.hint--always.hint--right:after,.hint--always.hint--right:before{-webkit-transform:translateX(8px);-moz-transform:translateX(8px);transform:translateX(8px)}.hint--rounded:after{border-radius:4px}.hint--no-animate:before,.hint--no-animate:after{-webkit-transition-duration:0ms;-moz-transition-duration:0ms;transition-duration:0ms}.hint--bounce:before,.hint--bounce:after{-webkit-transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,-webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.71,1.7,.77,1.24);-moz-transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,-moz-transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.71,1.7,.77,1.24);transition:opacity .3s ease,visibility .3s ease,transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.71,1.7,.77,1.24)}
.vote { background: url('vote.png') no-repeat top left; width: 20px; height: 20px;  } 
.vote.v_m7 { background-position: 0px 0px;  } 
.vote.v_p7 { background-position: 0px -30px;  } 
.vote.v_p6 { background-position: 0px -60px;  } 
.vote.v_m6 { background-position: 0px -90px;  } 
.vote.v_m5 { background-position: 0px -120px;  } 
.vote.v_p5 { background-position: 0px -150px;  } 
.vote.v_p4 { background-position: 0px -180px;  } 
.vote.v_m4 { background-position: 0px -210px;  } 
.vote.v_m3 { background-position: 0px -240px;  } 
.vote.v_p3 { background-position: 0px -270px;  } 
.vote.v_p2 { background-position: 0px -300px;  } 
.vote.v_m2 { background-position: 0px -330px;  } 
.vote.v_m1 { background-position: 0px -360px;  } 
.vote.v_p1 { background-position: 0px -390px;  } 
.vote.v_equal { background-position: 0px -420px;  }
.bc {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
    .friendcodes {
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .friendcodes tr > td {
        padding: 5px 25px;
    }
    .fc_premium {
        background: #ffdf8e;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .fc_regular {
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
    Use form below for Adding IDs
</h3>
<form action="http://shortcutcentral.org/projects/friendcodes/receiveQuery.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' value="481" name="id" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
    <h3>
        Current Testing Stuff
    </h3>
    <p>
<?php 
require('vote.php');
displayRating(481);
?>
    </p>
</body>
```

Here's the exact error for those of you who are keen on it - I've obfuscated some of the stuff here as well, since I am working from a live install:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare displayRating() (previously declared in /home/****/public_html/****/vote.php:2) in /home/****/public_html/****/vote.php on line 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both displayCodes.php and test.php are requiring vote.php, and the later is not doing a require_once. Switch test.php to require_once('vote.php');

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is ocurring because in your test.php code you are including vote.php with

require('vote.php');

and also you are requiring 'displayCodes.php' in test.php

The problem here is that you also call 'displayCodes.php' inside vote.php so the function is being declared two times. Try commenting this line in test.php

require('displayCodes.php');

so that way you are just including the function once.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, you are calling that file with the require function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the  `require_once('medoo.min.php');` in displayRating() method. You're caling displayRating() to a loop so it probably iclude medoo.min.php many times.